# Cauchy sequence is bounded? (Do we need any element in a sequence to be finite?)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

This question is related to the question [Is every cauchy sequence bounded?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1905035/is-every-cauchy-sequence-bounded?rq=1)
The sequence $\{a_n\}$ used in that question
              $$a_n=\frac{1}{n-1}$$

has the first element $a_1\rightarrow\infty$. As shown in the answer of that question, $a_1=\infty$ is not well-defined, so we can not say it is an unbounded Cauchy sequence.

However, in an unbounded sequence $$a_n=n,$$ we also have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n\rightarrow\infty.$$ Why $\infty$ works here?

Comment: $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n \rightarrow \infty$ means that the sequences fails to converge, or that it diverges. It does not converge to infinity, because infinity is not a number (you can extend the real numbers to include $\infty$ or $-\infty$, but that is notational convenience; if you are studying sequences like these, $\infty$ is a process that grows arbitrarily large in absolute value).

Comment: what is an example of a sequence with an element that is infinite?

Comment: @justaguy In fact this is my question. Why we can not use $\infty$ in a sequence? I can write by hand a sequence as $\{\infty, 1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...\}$. The definition of sequence itself does not forbid it.

Comment: infinity is not a quantity so it isn't something you can claim as the element of a sequence. It is simply the notion of unboundedness.

Comment: @justaguy Seems that a sequence need not to be a sequence of number? And in an unbounded sequence $\{a_n=n\}$, the $\infty=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n$ still exist?

Comment: @Renard if we include $\infty$ in the set, does that means that the Cauchy sequence defined at that set is no more bounded?

Comment: If you include $\infty$ in your set, you need to define what the distance from a number to $\infty$ means. Otherwise, the limit-definition (based on a metric or open sets) does not make sense. If you don't define your metric/topology on that set, you can not talk about convergente sequence or Cauchy sequences.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line .  Notice how careful the language is about Cauchy sequences in the "Limits" section.

Comment: A sequence is typically a function that maps $\mathbb{N}$ into $\mathbb{R}$.  If you want to define it differently, you can, but the rules change and you can't assume that all of the things you proved about standard sequences apply exactly the same way. There are also significant generalizations of sequences, like nets or filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_n = +\infty$ means that for each $M \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$ 
$$a_n > M.$$

This means that the terms of the sequence get arbitrarily large.

Note that in your first sequence you somehow claim that $\infty$ is an element of that sequence, but it is a concept to denote unboundedness, it can not be an element of a sequence.

**edit:** proof that $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n = + \infty$ with $a_n = n \in \mathbb{N}$ :

Choose $M \in \mathbb{R}$ arbitrarily, then there exists a natural number $n_0$ with $n_0 > M$ (fundamental property of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $n \geq n_0$, then 
$$a_n = n \geq n_0 > M.$$
This proves that $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n = + \infty$.

However, it can be 'the limit of a sequence', as the definition above states.

Comment: So, you mean that even in $\{a_n=n\}$, every element is finite, even when $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: yes, $\to$ means 'approaches'. It does not need to 'hit' that limit. For example $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, but there is no $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n} = 0$.

Comment: So in sequence (either bounded or unbounded), we are always talking about a set of **finite** numbers (maybe arbitrary large, but still finite)?

Comment: If we are talking about a real sequence (= sequence with as elements real numbers), then yes. However, the sequence notion can be defined in any topological space (where convergence is defined in terms of open sets). https://wolfweb.unr.edu/homepage/jabuka/Classes/2006_spring/topology/Notes/04%20-%20Congergent%20sequences.pdf

Comment: In those general case, if the metric is not used, is there any thing equivalent to the "finite" in reals?

Comment: @Xliu i don't understand your question... You can define sequences and convergence in any topological space. However, that set could be the set of real functions for example. What does it mean to have a finite function? You then need to define what finite means in that space.

Comment: Just check your links. Seems I get the idea. The convergence here or 'finite' here means all can be included in one open set.

Comment: @Xliu glad it makes sense :)